# Intercept theorem in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

The celebrated intercept theorem(also known as Thales's theorem) provides the ratios between the line segments created when two parallel lines are intercepted by two intersecting lines.

I'm looking for a reference for a generalization of the intercept theorem in $\mathbb R^n$, where it discusses the volume in $\mathbb R^n$ instead of the lengths.